# A binary I compiled on one version of OSX does not work on another. How to make a portable binary?

Tags: ruby, macos, compilation, portability, dylib

I compiled a binary on my OSX system (Sierra - 10.12.6) that i'm trying to share with a friend on Mavericks (10.9.2) 
However when he tries to run the binary he gets strange errors:

```
 "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime"
 referenced from foo/ruby (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
```

My question is how do i compile a binary so that it works on both my system and on his? In this particular case the binary is the Ruby executable, but I assume this applies to other binaries too.

If possible i would also appreciate an explanation for why this doesn't work and why I'm getting the error i am.

Comment: https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool/issues/1777#issuecomment-248267151 seems to be a good description of the issue.

Comment: If you search here for "_clock_gettime" (with or without "ruby"), there's lots of other questions like this.  The most common answers seem to be "upgrade to at least 10.12" or "patch the program to not require `_clock_gettime`".  How involved do you want to get?